# Excel VBA splititng data into colums without duplicating

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that goes through a huge list of data and that would split into columns parts of the data according to some criteria. Please not that there is no pattern that can be hard coded since in the example below the number of dependants can change drastically.

As of now, my data looks like this.
[image]

I would want it like this
[image]

I've written some code that goes through everything, and write each dependent on a new column but that create duplicates. I'm not able to detect whether that value was already on the row or not. Here is the code that I tried to write. ***Take not that we're already in the context of looping through every row.***

```
dim isUnique 
            For i = 1 To 100
                If  not WsT.Cells(Rt, i).Value =  .Cells(NbcDepfname).Value Then 
                    isUnique = true
                else 
                    isUnique = false
                End If
            Next i
              Ct = 10

              If isUnique Then
                  WsT.Cells(Rt, Ct).Value = .Cells(NbcDepLname).Value
                  WsT.Cells(Rt, Ct + 1).Value = .Cells(NbcDepfname).Value
                  WsT.Cells(Rt, Ct + 2).Value = .Cells(NbcDepBDate).Value

            End If
        End With
```

I have very little experience with VBA and macros so my approach might not be the best or good at all. I've noticed also huge performance drops with that approach but it's alright for that project.

**EDIT ******
I understand my mistake perfectly. I'm looping through "EVERY" row of the first sheet with the unformatted data. I don't check correctly if the data is unique for that row before writing it, therefore, It will obviously keep writing a dependant per row. I tried with dictionaries but since it is possible that a dependant has both the same name and birthdate as another one on another row with different parents i couldn't keep that solution. The detection has to be done at the Row level.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that you might have two dependents of the same name, spouse and child. Therefore I added another test to my previous solution to check the DoB. Here is the extended version.

```
Private Function IsUnique(ByVal DepName As String, _
                          DepDob As String, _
                          Ws As Worksheet, _
                          R As Long) As Boolean
    ' 11 Apr 2017

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Dob As Variant
    Dim C As Long

    With Ws.Rows(R)
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(NedDependt), .Cells(Ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    End With
    DepName = Trim(DepName)

    With Rng
        For C = (.Cells.Count - 1) To 1 Step ((NedDepDob + 1) * -1)
            If StrComp(Trim(.Cells(C).Value), DepName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Dob = .Cells(C + NedDepDob).Value
                If IsDate(Dob) Then
                    If IsDate(DepDob) Then
                        If CDate(Dob) = CDate(DepDob) Then Exit For
                    Else
                        If Trim(Dob) = Trim(DepDob) Then Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                    If Trim(Dob) = Trim(DepDob) Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next C
    End With

    IsUnique = (C < 1)
End Function
```

For the purpose of this procedure I created a new enumeration which replaces the previous `Enum Nfd`. The new enum is adjusted to the actual columns as you published them above. You might need it not Private, if you refer to it in modules other than where it is located.

```
Private Enum Ned                        ' worksheet Employee Data
    NedFirstDataRow = 2                 ' Adjust as required
    NedName = 1                         ' columns:
    NedFname
    NedEmployed
    NedDependt
    NedDepName = 0                       ' Offset from NedDependt
    NedDepDob
End Enum
```

Below is the calling procedure I used for testing. Once you integrate the function into your project, the worksheet should be the one containing the formatted data while name, Dob and the row are variables.

```
Private Sub TestIsUnique()
    Debug.Print IsUnique("vanessa", "1/12/1976", ActiveSheet, 9)
    Debug.Print IsUnique("vanessa", "01/02/1976", ActiveSheet, 9)
End Sub
```

The date is a bit of a problem. I notice that you use yyyy/mm/ddd. The code will have no problem with that, but it may have a problem if the dates in your data are strings. I programmed it so that the code will first attempt to compare actual dates but will compare strings if one of the values can't be converted to a date.

Comment: I've been trying to implement your code but i keep on getting the error message Method Range of Object _Worksheet failed.

I hard coded some values as such
Set Rng = Range(.Cells(44), .Cells(Ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count)) but still got an error.

Comment: I tested the code before posting. The error message you get points to the worksheet object you pass to the function not having been set. Check where you get it from. Perhaps you have it everywhere in your project except in the proc from where you want to call the new function. Sh happens :-). Test the function using exactly my calling procedure while the sheet you want to work on is active.

Comment: Hi Again, I've tried to implement your code and i still get the same error with the range object.
The thing is i don't fully understand the range object therefore i'm unable to solve it.
I've posted my code here https://codeshare.io/axLrBL. At Line 176 I call IsUnique() with the correct parameters. I made sure that the Worksheet passed in params
is the one with the formatted data. But at that point in the code, I'm in the context of looping through Every Row of the Sheet with
the unformatted data. Could it be interfering? Also take note that now i added a unique employee id per person.

Comment: This is what I get with my current code and again,
http://imageshack.com/a/img924/5739/7F6snZ.jpg
Is there any way I could do my detection at the row level ? I edited the main post to explain a little further. By the way thanks a lot for your help. I learned alot reading your code and your explanations.

Comment: Sorry, Codeshare gives me a black screen, apparently expecting a log-in to view shared code. Imageshack gives me "This page can't be displayed". A "Range" is one or more cells. Its properties define many things about it, such as `Range.Worksheet`, `Range.Cells.Count` and `Range.Cells(1).Value` or `Range.Cells(1).Formula` You must set a range variable using the keyword `Set`. Place a `MsgBox "Here"` into the function to see where the error occurs. I suspect its in the function call and that you are trying to pass an object as `Worksheet` argument which is not a worksheet object.

Comment: What do you mean by "doing the detection at row level"? You should be looping through your raw data and detect for each row whether it's a different employee. If it is the same employ, check the listed dependents and add those note previously known. The process might lead to discarded entries. Write those into a sheet, call it "Unresolved" so that you can look at them. You might add a note, such as "duplicate dependent" (can't think of any other reason fro discarding right now). If you find no other way, create a one-time use email address and post it here. I will respond.

Comment: Infighter77@Live.ca send me a message so we can discuss

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes to the routine I posted in your [previous, very similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011455/excel-macro-append-duplicates-to-first-line), is all that is needed.  That routine already uses dictionaries to check on duplicates, so it was merely a matter of adapting to your slightly different layout in this thread.

Of note, this requires, obviously, that the "Main" person be identified by a combination of `FirstNameLastName + EmploymentDate`.  However, it does NOT require that the list be sorted.

It should adapt to any number of unique Dependent Name / BirthDate pairs.

It will Clear the entire Results worksheet before writing the results.

Be sure to read the notes in the different modules.  They are critical to having it run.  You will use two Class Modules and one Regular Module

### Class 1

---

```
Option Explicit
'Rename this module: cDependents
'set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Private pBirthDt As Date
Private pDepName As String

Public Property Get BirthDt() As Date
    BirthDt = pBirthDt
End Property
Public Property Let BirthDt(Value As Date)
    pBirthDt = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DepName() As String
    DepName = pDepName
End Property
Public Property Let DepName(Value As String)
    pDepName = Value
End Property
```

---

### Class 2

---

```
Option Explicit
'rename this module: cFamily
'set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Private pFirstName As String
Private pLastName As String
Private pBirthDate As Date
Private pEmploymentDate As Date
Private pDependents As Dictionary

Public Property Get FirstName() As String
    FirstName = pFirstName
End Property
Public Property Let FirstName(Value As String)
    pFirstName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LastName() As String
    LastName = pLastName
End Property
Public Property Let LastName(Value As String)
    pLastName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get BirthDate() As Date
    BirthDate = pBirthDate
End Property
Public Property Let BirthDate(Value As Date)
    pBirthDate = Value
End Property

Public Property Get EmploymentDate() As Date
    EmploymentDate = pEmploymentDate
End Property
Public Property Let EmploymentDate(Value As Date)
    pEmploymentDate = Value
End Property

Public Function ADDDependents(BrthDt, Name)
    Dim cD As New cDependents
    Dim sKey As String
    With cD
        .DepName = Name
        .BirthDt = BrthDt
        sKey = .BirthDt & Chr(1) & .DepName
    End With

    If Not pDependents.Exists(sKey) Then
        pDependents.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=cD
    End If
End Function

Public Property Get Dependents() As Dictionary
    Set Dependents = pDependents
End Property


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pDependents = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

---

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
'set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub Family()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dF As Dictionary, cF As cFamily
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant

'Set source and results worksheets and results range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'read source data into array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=5)
End With

'Collect and organize the family and dependent objects
Set dF = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cF = New cFamily
    With cF
        .LastName = vSrc(I, 1)
        .FirstName = vSrc(I, 2)
        .EmploymentDate = vSrc(I, 3)
        .ADDDependents vSrc(I, 5), vSrc(I, 4)
        sKey = .LastName & .FirstName & .EmploymentDate
        If Not dF.Exists(sKey) Then
            dF.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=cF
        Else
            dF(sKey).ADDDependents vSrc(I, 5), vSrc(I, 4)
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Results will have two columns for each relation
' + three columns at the beginning

'get number of extra columns
    Dim ColCount As Long
    For Each V In dF
        I = dF(V).Dependents.Count
        ColCount = IIf(I > ColCount, I, ColCount)
    Next V
    ColCount = ColCount * 2 + 3


ReDim vRes(0 To dF.Count, 1 To ColCount)
    vRes(0, 1) = "Last Name"
    vRes(0, 2) = "First Name"
    vRes(0, 3) = "Employment Date"

    For J = 4 To UBound(vRes, 2) Step 2
        vRes(0, J) = "Dependent Name "
        vRes(0, J + 1) = "Dependent BirthDate"
    Next J


I = 0
For Each V In dF
    I = I + 1
    With dF(V)
        vRes(I, 1) = .LastName
        vRes(I, 2) = .FirstName
        vRes(I, 3) = .EmploymentDate

        J = 2
        For Each W In .Dependents
            J = J + 2
            With .Dependents(W)
                vRes(I, J) = .DepName
                vRes(I, J + 1) = .BirthDt
            End With
        Next W
    End With
Next V

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .Worksheet.Cells.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Interior.Color = vbBlue
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    For I = 3 To .Columns.Count - 1 Step 2
        .Columns(I).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    Next I
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

---

### Results when run on your data above

[image]

Comment: Hi, Ron, I know it's very similar but I have my back against the wall here. I've tried for a week to solve find a solution. The problem I'm having is the same on your result screenshot. Since the number of dependent changes drastically the code keeps writing duplicates until he's done looping through every row. All i need is a way to check if it's the first time you're writing a dependent before you're writing it. Look at your example, Jessica is here twice but she should be there only once. However your code does work for Sophie.

Comment: @Maken The two Jessica's listed here have two different Birthdates in your original data. How do you want to handle that situation?  I assumed they were two different people with the same first name.  But the routine could be easily altered to only retain one.  But which one?

Comment: I've been reading & experimenting with your code and it does work. Your code is a little more complicated to understand but bare with me. I have two question. Now I added a unique Id per employee so i could target the dependants of that employees better. I see in your code that in the function add dependants it's where you check with the Skey. i tried to modify it but now i get subscript out of range error. I did modify the class to add all the fields that i would need.

To help you understand better  this google sheet has a 1/1 exemple of my data

Comment: What i have so far
.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_aDGZUXuufSjawaLayAjsBSn3NX09-w75G9VzgEblHc/edit#gid=0

The sheet here is what i'm looking for.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_aDGZUXuufSjawaLayAjsBSn3NX09-w75G9VzgEblHc/edit#gid=353135431

Here is my code where i added all my variables
http://pasted.co/75a1a117

Comment: @Maken You never responded to my question about what to do with the two Jessica's that have different birthdates.  You also did not show the line of code gave you the `subscript out of range` error, although I can see that you never dimension `vRes` properly.  Nor are you collecting the other variables in your objects.  To go from your question above, to what you want, using my technique, will require a good understanding of the code, VBA arrays and classes. For classes, I suggest [Chip Pearson's Introduction to classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx).